# remove 'publishing options' and other settings from node/add

Tags: users

I have a role which allows users to add nodes, viewing the admin form, but I don't want the user to be able to see [image] Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the @jdu answer is correct and should suffice for most people, it's just two lines of code but might save some time for someone:

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if (isset($form['#node']) && $form['#node']->type == 'article') {
    // hide article options 
    $form['options']['#access'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hook_form_alter() or use CSS if you don't care if the values are overridden.